# Filter to existing web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm looking for a simple example to connect two web parts to eachother.

1. My own filter web part
2. Existing list (For getting filter values)

I'm developping my application for Sharepoint 2010 and i cant seem to find any good tutorial which does not implement deprecated / obsolete functions. Can anyone point me to an example or has a simple example available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done it for me:

http://www.rexsoft.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=82:connecting-web-parts&catid=42:sharepoint-briefing&Itemid=82

Answer (score 1):

On MSDN is a [Getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx) on connecting web parts.

This will provide you with basic knowledge on connected web parts.

Comment: That tutorial is about creating connectable web parts. It does not supply information about how to create your own filter provider that can connect to an existing list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010033786), perhaps?

Comment: No, i'm looking for the actual implementation on how to create a filter provider for an existing list.